# 240V Four Prong Outlet - Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, dryer, 240v

An odd issue arose with my dryer outlet, and I am more concerned than initially. Below are the chain of events:

1. Dryer:

- Samsung dryer spun, but did not heat

  - Replaced heating element
  - Plugged in, did not power on
  - Troubleshooting dryer, thought it was the circuit panel
- Purchased new dryer

  - Plugged in, did not power on

2. Electric:

- Outlet:

  - Left Hot (Black) to Right Hot (Red) = 240
- Outlet one week later:

  - Left Hot (Black) to Right Hot (Red) = 94
  - Neutral to RH (Red) = 120
  - Neutral to LH (Black) = 27
  - Ground to LH (Black) = 27
  - Ground to RH (Red) =120
  - ** could not read 240v again..
- Behind Outlet:

  - Ground to LH (Black) = 27
  - Ground to RH (Red) = 120
- Breaker panel:

  - Main Power Off

    - Removed Breaker door
    - Tightened all breaker screws (not neutral's)
  - Main Power On

    - Tested:

      - Ground to Top Breaker (Black) = 120
      - Ground to Bottom Breaker (Red) = 120
      - Both = 240
- Outlet Tested:

  - LH (Black) to RH (Red) = 240
  - Neutral to RH (Red) = 120
  - Neutral to LH (Black) = 120
  - Ground to LH (Black) = 120
  - Ground to RH (Red) =120
- Plugged Dryer In, did not power on..
- Later:

  - LH (Black) to RH (Red) = 240
  - Neutral to RH (Red) = 120
  - Neutral to LH (Black) = 120
  - Ground to LH (Black) = 120
  - Ground to RH (Red) =120
  - Ground to Neutral = 0
  - Dryer Breaker Off
  - Continuity Ground to Neutral = Correct
- Plugged Samsung in, it worked

  - Unplugged Samsung
- Plugged Maytag in, it worked

From reading, it may a faulty breaker. Any ideas? Cannot get an electrician for another couple weeks
[image: 4 Prong Outlet]

[image: Panel Box]

Comment: When plugging into the receptacle, is it stiff or easy?  It should be stiff and need to have a good push.

Comment: Stiff, as in one hand on wall to remove cord from outlet, outlet itself is around 2 years old.

Comment: Did you use a torque driver when tightening screws? Why didn't you do the neutral while you were at it?

Answer (score 6):

As I read your description, and this may just be an omission, I don't see you checking the torque on the receptacle wire connecting screws; I also don't see mention of using a torque driver on the breaker screws.

Since the problem stinks of being a bad connection, you should go over **every** connection (both hots, neutral, and ground - at both ends, and any junctions in the middle) looking for problems and leaving them tightened to the proper torque specification.

Comment: I just checked the receptacle wire connecting screws. The LH (black wire) was tight, but the screw was not seated directly on the wire, as the right was. I just fixed that. As for the neutral bar, can I shut the main breaker off, and then torque all neutral screws? FWIW when I torqued the breaker screws, all where already correct. When I am in there, I may as well remove the breaker and inspect the back.

Comment: Curious though, would a loose wire at the receptacle affect the reading of the wire itself (behind the outlet). Because initial testing showed that loose wire reading 27V.

Comment: That may have been a bad connection elsewhere. But it's very consistent with "everything read fine, neither dryer worked" as tested later, followed by "Both dryers mysteriously started working after that." With poor connections, there's no good reason to expect only one, as presumably **every** connection here was made by someone who did not to a careful and correct job on at least one or two. Can you post a picture of the receptacle terminals? Most have a shoe or clamp that should be *between* the screw and the wire, rather than the screw bearing directly on the wire.

Comment: Good point, let me check the torque on the neutral screws in panel box.

Comment: Quick recap and want to state items I checked based on your suggestions. 
Days of inconsistent readings, I powered off main breaker, torqued all breaker screws (but they were already fine).
I powered on main breaker, tested the 240v breaker wires, all correct. Tested receptacle, all correct.
At this point, I plugged in dryer, no dice.
However, after 240V breakers off/on/off/on while checking continuity and moving dryers around, I checked once more, and both dryers powered on and heat worked.
But I am apprehensive that I am missing something more important.

Comment: Via your comments, I re-tightened the black hot at receptacle (the one with inconsistent readings), it was not seated into the "cradle" as the other side was. 

Then I went back to the panel and confirmed the correct torque of all neutral screws. 

Again, perfect readings and dryer(s) work.

For your question about the receptacle terminals, let me get you a photo later today, but the model is Pass & Seymour 30 Amp #3864CC6

Answer (score 4):

Pull and replace the breaker, they're cheap.  Use the proper breaker for your panel, the types are not interchangeable, e.g. a BR, THQL or QP does not belong in a HOM panel.

I'm not at all happy with the strategy of taking a suspect (or proven faulty) connection and simply torquing the screw more and hanging the "Mission Accomplished" banner on the aircraft carrier.  If the contact is poor, there's likely to be some arcing, oxidation and soot in there. The wire should be removed, inspected, cleaned up if necessary and put back in, or you're just torquing down oxide, and you'll have spotty results.